# Broken CURL on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: php, curl

I recently ran into an issue with Stripe.com requiring TLS 1.2 for their API.

I **attempted** to upgrade OpenSSL on the server following the below steps, but afterwards when attempting to run **curl_version()**, I get this error:

> Call to undefined function curl_version()

However, before I attempted this update, CURL was working fine (except for the TLS issue).

**This is the process that I followed:**

I downloaded the OpenSSL binaries here: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2j-x64_86-win64.zip

Stopped IIS
Copied libeay32.dll & ssleay32.dll to the PHP folder (where the older versions were located)

Restarted IIS

**My System is:**

**OS:** Windows 2008 RS2 64bit

### **PHP Version:** 5.3.8

I was hoping I didn't need to compile PHP and reinstall a new version right now.

I appreciate your assistance

Thank You.

Comment: The PHP curl extension is now possibly failing to load because it is linked against an older OpenSSL version, so you may need to get a more updated curl version.  Error log may also show some curl related errors on PHP startup.

Comment: Thank you. I went to the cURL website for downloading the newest version but I can't figure out how to update it on the server.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of grabbing it from http://windows.php.net/download/ - kinda forgot you're on an old unsupported version though.  Maybe try getting php_curl.dll from the ext dir in http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.3.29-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip and see if that works.  Otherwise, the problem is gonna be these old DLLs are linked against older versions of OpenSSL and won't be compatible unless you install a newer version of PHP.

Comment: I tried that and had various issues. I was concerned about changing PHP versions affecting other websites I forgot that IIS can have different versions of PHP installed, so I just installed PHP 5.8.26 (I know its not the newest version) that just turned out to the best simplest cleanest solution. 

Thanks for your help @drew010

Answer (score 2):

After many various attempts, I gave up and just installed a newer version of PHP. I forgot that IIS can have multiple versions of PHP installed, so this turned out to be the best bet and frankly the easiest solution for me.